# getting the <BLOB Memo> in dbf file

Tags: c#, dbf

I am trying to insert values by reading them from XML file and inserting them in dbase file. When I am executing my code, I am only getting the values  in each field, I am not getting the actual value that I am reading from the XML file. below is the code:

```
 private static void ReadXMLFile()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"tblTest.xml");
        DistName dist = new DistName();
        string folderPath = @"C:\folder\";
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + folderPath + "; Extended Properties=DBASE III;";
        var Rows = from row in doc.Descendants("row")
                   select new
                   {
                       Code = row.Element("code").Value,
                       Name = row.Element("Name").Value,
                       Type =  row.Element("type").Value,

                   };

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();

            foreach (var row in Rows)
            {
                dist.Code = row.Code;
                dist.Name = row.Name;
                dist.Type = row.Type;


                command.CommandText = insertStatment(dist);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }


    }
```

My insert statement looks like below:

```
    StringBuilder sqlstmt = new StringBuilder();
        sqlstmt.Append("INSERT INTO tblNAME (CODE, NAME, TYPE  )");
        sqlstmt.Append(" Values ( '" +  dist.Code + "','");
        sqlstmt.Append(dist.Name + "','");
        sqlstmt.Append(dist.Type  "'" + ")");
```

This is how I created my dbf file

```
private static void CreateDBFFile()
    {
        //   string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\folder";
        string folderPath = @"C:\folder\";
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + folderPath + "; Extended Properties=DBASE III;";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE DISTNAME (CODE TEXT, NAME TEXT, TYPE Text)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
   }
```

I checked the values and there are actual values coming, but when I opened the dbf file, I only see  in each field.  Below is the image of the values that I am getting in the table:

[image: values from the table]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what values are getting in your table?

Comment: showed the value above

Comment: what program are you using to view the dbf?  It may not handle blob fields and just show some generic text instead.

Comment: Try querying that field using C#.  See what you get.